# How to use pd.cut to bin data in a natural way?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas Series of 100 float data points and I need to put them into 10 equally wide bins, and I need to access, say, the indices of the data in the fourth bin. Then what I tried is:

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
cut = pd.cut(s, bins=10, labels=range(10))
fourth_bin = s[cut == 4]
fourth_bin
Out[101]: 
9    -0.249370
12   -0.322417
13   -0.384054
16   -0.172428
26   -0.122890
28   -0.267888
31   -0.396754
40   -0.191836
51   -0.352250
53   -0.349343
54   -0.208894
63   -0.298093
65   -0.075572
71   -0.504466
76   -0.306204
80   -0.222328
81   -0.200758
92   -0.375285
96   -0.343854
dtype: float64
```

which isn't quite natural and looks even a bit clumsy. For example, can I avoid manually setting the `labels` and just start from `pd.cut(s, bins=10)`? This way I want to do something like

```
s[s in pd.cut(s, bins=10).categories[4]]
```

since `categories` is a list of `Interval`s, but this doesn't work out.

Is there a more natural way to do this so I don't have to manually set `labels`?

Comment: Do you mean `pd.qcut(s, 10, labels=False)`

Comment: @piRSquared wow this one's slick and extremely clear! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pd.qcut`

For evenly sized bins

```
np.random.seed(1)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))

cut = pd.qcut(s, 10, labels=False)
fourth_bin = s[cut == 4]

fourth_bin

16   -0.172428
18    0.042214
26   -0.122890
35   -0.012665
40   -0.191836
44    0.050808
54   -0.208894
65   -0.075572
81   -0.200758
97    0.043597
dtype: float64
```

---

#### `pd.cut`

For evenly spaced bins

```
np.random.seed(1)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))

cut = pd.cut(s, 10, labels=False)
fourth_bin = s[cut == 4]
fourth_bin

9    -0.249370
12   -0.322417
13   -0.384054
16   -0.172428
26   -0.122890
28   -0.267888
31   -0.396754
40   -0.191836
51   -0.352250
53   -0.349343
54   -0.208894
63   -0.298093
65   -0.075572
71   -0.504466
76   -0.306204
80   -0.222328
81   -0.200758
92   -0.375285
96   -0.343854
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Don't understand why it worked differently from `cut = pd.cut(s, bins=10, labels=range(10))`.

Comment: @Vim `pd.qcut` is supposed to divide the data into equal sized groups.  `pd.cut` divides into groups of 10 evenly spaced groups.  The trick for labels is to set it to `False`

Comment: Ok I didn't notice you used `pd.qcut` in place of `pd.cut`. Also thanks for the tip, now I understand how to deal with both cases.

Comment: Just another followup question: if we use `pd.cut` with `labels` turned off, then is it still possible to know the exact boundaries of each interval? For example can we still access the right endpoint of, say, the fourth bin? (Note that it's not necessarily `max(fourth_bin)` because no data point has to land right on the boundary.)

Comment: use the `retbins=True` flag.   `cut, bins = pd.cut(s, 10, labels=False, retbins=True)`